# Does flutter web only support rendering everything in canvas?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using Flutter to build a web application and I can't inspect any element since they are all in canvas. I have read [this doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers) and it mentions to use `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html` to render in html, but I found it is still rendering everything in canvas.

so the question is whether flutter support rendering elements in basic html elements like `div, form, input` etc. If not, is the only way to inspect elements via flutter debugger? It is not handy if I can't inspect elements since debugger doesn't work for production build.

Comment: Why would you want the debugger on a release build? Flutter does not render in the basic html elements you describe, likely just due to lack of flexibility with those elements, so the only way to do it is through devtools. If you read the document you linked, Flutter "Uses a *combination* of HTML elements, CSS, Canvas elements, and SVG elements."

Comment: The reason I use debugger is to be able to inspect elements in product build. For example, if there is any UI issues found in prod, I'd like to inspect the elements and analyse the root course.

Comment: Are there any problems/differences you anticipate having from using dart2js instead of dartdevc? Have you tried using profile builds instead of release? For mobile, devtools can still be used, though I'm not really sure for web. Probably not since it uses dart2js, but worth a shot. It wasn't clear if you had tried this since you only said "production build". If using a profile build doesn't work, the answer to this question is probably a hard no.